# Remote SQLite manager

Tags: php, sqlite, remote-access

Does someone know of a Sqlite manager that I can put on my site, so that I can access it over the web and create/edit SQlite databases. I guess something like phpMyAdmin for MySQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try http://www.sqlitemanager.org/

It supports sqlite version 2 and 3 (version 1.2)

Comment: SQLiteManager has not been updated since 2010, so it does not support all the recent SQLite features...

Comment: @ChristopherK. you know, the answer dates back to 2010. Have you a better/updated solution to propose? I would eagerly update (with credits) the answer to add it (or you can add a reply by yourself).

Comment: yeah I know the answer is old. I just wanted to comment that people reading it today see it might not the best option nowadays. I am developer of phpLiteAdmin which is proposed in the other answers, so I would propose this, but I might be biased ;) At least development of phpLiteAdmin is still active (last stable release in December, last commit 5 days ago).

Answer (score 5):

try [https://www.phpliteadmin.org](https://www.phpliteadmin.org/)

This is the best web-based SQLite manager I've used so far. It is very easy to install and can do basically anything you would ever want to do with a SQLite database. It supports both SQLite2 and SQLite3. It even says on its web site that its goal is to be the SQLite equivalent of phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 3):

phpLiteAdmin is a single php file and it is a php-based, web-based phpMyAdmin-like SQLite manager:
http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools